# Why is the unless statement used here, when in my mind a while would have been correct?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, controls

Code was given to my by superiors (coders) to dissect and understand. One piece of logic is doing my head in because I cannot see it right. They are on holiday and unavailable.

```
def check_in_guests(guests)
  checked_in_guests = 0
  return checked_in_guests unless is_available?(guests)

  guests.each do |guest|
    next unless guest.sufficient_funds_for_entry?(@room_cost)

    check_in_guest(guest)
    checked_in_guests += 1
  end
end
```

Unless `is_available?` does not work there.

```
def is_available?(guests)
  return number_of_guests <= free_spaces && free_spaces != 0
end
```

If there are more guests than free spaces, then the function returns false. However, if there are more guests than free spaces, the above code runs and performs the relevant operations which should only be run if guests are lower than free spaces. Any ideas? Have my teachers made a mistake? Should it be while instead of unless? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Where are `number_of_guests` and `free_spaces` defined? Why to you pass `guests` to `is_available?`, but don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_in_guests(guests)
  checked_in_guests = 0
  return checked_in_guests unless is_available?(guests)

  guests.each do |guest|
    next unless guest.sufficient_funds_for_entry?(@room_cost)

    check_in_guest(guest)
    checked_in_guests += 1
  end
end

def is_available?(guests)
  return number_of_guests <= free_spaces && free_spaces != 0
end
```

What your code is doing is returning the total number of checked in guests if the `is_available?` return false. You can think of `unless` as `if not`. Then we can look into the `is_available?` method, I'm going to assume `number_of_guests` is the same as `guests.length`, also assuming `guests` is passed in as an array. It looks like this method is part of a class, so I'm guessing `free_spaces` is previously defined.

Let's use some concrete examples, say you have 10 free spaces and 15 guests, there's no way to check in everyone, so `number_of_guests` is less than `free_spaces`, so `is_available?` returns false, and `check_in_guests` return the checked_in_guests`and not execute the`.each` block.

If you have 10 spaces and 5 guests, the return statement does not execute, and we execute the `.each` block.

Comment: Guests is an array and guests.count is used somewhere else in the code, you are correct. You are saying that the  `ìs_available?`should return `true` to execute the code below it? Then why not use `while`

Comment: The reason why the code below it does not execute is because of the `return` statement. The method ends when a `return` is executed. `unless` is the opposite of `if`, so both are conditional statements. `while` is used for looping, and its opposite is `until`.

Comment: Once  `ìs_available?` becomes true the block `guests.each`runs. I think the block shield was really confusing me. Thanks a lot @davidhu2000